# How to get an object in Grails by ID when using MongoDB and the ID is an object?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have created a project on Grails 2.2.2 and I have installed the MongoDB plugin. It is all working fine. I just have one question... The id field in my domain classes is Object id, as recommended, but then again, of course, doing Person.get(id), doesn't work, because id is an Object, not a Long or String. Any ideas?

Cheers,
Iraklis

Comment: When you do `Person.get(id)` what do you use as `id`?

Comment: Of course, you are right, I am referring to the default scaffolding where the id passed is from the params and it is a String. So, any ideas?

Comment: Create an [ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6.5/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) out of the string and use is as `id`. Simple. :)

Comment: Thanks, but it is a bit more complicated I guess, this is my issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907221/grails-with-mongodb-object-id-and-scaffold

Comment: I hope you have your answer now.

Comment: Embarrassingly no, I tried changing the scaffolding code, no luck... getting String id and creating an ObjectId out of it, no luck so far :-(

Comment: Could you show what you tried? I'm no Grails expert, but the ObjectId class looks fairly straight forward to use.

Comment: I tried passing (String id) in the show method in the controller, and then I did def personInstance = Person.get(new ObjectId(id))

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it seems like using Object id is not working with scaffolding. I changed the field to String id, and in the scaffolding Controller, changed all the references of Long id to String id and works like a charm.